# Where to reset a button state after programmatically making a phone call

Tags: ios, swift

My issue is that when pressing a button to make a phone call, my button animates (turning the phone image 90 degrees).

But after the phone call ended and my view reappears, I want my button to reset to default state, but I don't know where exactly to call the code.

From what I look, `viewDidLayoutSubviews/viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called when my view reappears.
Is this a good place to call my code ? From what I saw both of them are called twice. Is there another place I could do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews/viewWillLayoutSubviews` are called multiple times, as per changing state of a button , yeah it would be a good place to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)` is called when ending an in App Phone Call.

If your call function looks something like this:

```
func call() {

    guard let url = NSURL(string: "tel://001234567890") else {
        return
    }

    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

    if (application.canOpenURL(url)) {
        application.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

And you want to do something when the call ends you can use the function from `App Delegate` : `applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)`

My reset looked like this :

```
guard let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first, let tabBar = window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else {
        return
}

tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
```

This basically turned a TabBar Item into a Call button.